# Напишите функцию check, которая принимает 2 аргумента -- указатели на int

Tags: c++, c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void check(int* a, int* b) {
    if (*a != *b) {
        *a = 1;
        *b = 1;

    }

    if (*a == *b) {
        *a = 0;
        *b = 0;

    }
}

int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    check(&a, &b);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

я понимаю, что в задании просят ввести только функцию, я использую блок main() как проверку

Comment: Вам надо сравнивать *указатели*, а вы сравниваете значения, на которые они указывают...

Comment: Небольшой комментарий по логике. Обратите внимание: в первом ```if```, если он сработал - вы запишете в переменные одинаковые значения. После этого отработает вторая проверка. К этому моменту в переменных ГАРАНТИРОВАНО лежат одинаковые значения. И в обе переменные будут записаны нули. То есть, ```независимо от начальных данных, после выполнения функции обе переменные будут содержать нули```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вам справедливо заметили в комментариях, сравнивать надо указатели.

```
void check(int*a,int*b) {
    if (a != b) *a = *b = 1;
    else *a = 0;
    }
```

Можно даже проще :) -

```
void check(int*a,int*b) {
    *a = *b = (a != b);
    }
```